# How to infer type of object element accessed via computed property?

Tags: typescript

I try to access an object element via a computed property. I know for a fact, that this computed string will be of a certain form, which corresponds to elements of certain types. Yet TypeScript infers any as type, because 'Boundary has no index signature'.

So far, the only thing that worked was casting the accessor string as a union of all possible values that it can take, but shouldn't TypeScript be able to interfere that automatically?

Example code below:

```
type Direction =
  | 'top'
  | 'bottom'
  | 'left'
  | 'right'
  | 'topLeft'
  | 'topRight'
  | 'bottomLeft'
  | 'bottomRight';

interface Boundary {
  top: number;
  topAlternatives: number[];
  bottom: number;
  bottomAlternatives: number[];
  left: number;
  leftAlternatives: number[];
  right: number;
  rightAlternatives: number[];
  topLeft: number;
  topLeftAlternatives: number[];
  topRight: number;
  topRightAlternatives: number[];
  bottomLeft: number;
  bottomLeftAlternatives: number[];
  bottomRight: number;
  bottomRightAlternatives: number[];
}

const direction: Direction = 'top';
const accessorString = `${direction}Alternatives`;

const object: Boundary = {...};
const element = object[accessorString]; // type is clearly number[], but it is not infered
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript can't infer string literal types when you do string manipulations. So even though it is obvious to us `accessorString` is `'topAlternatives'` typescript does not know this.

You can cast to `keyof Boundary` but then the result will be `number | number[]`

```
const direction: Direction = 'top';
const accessorString = `${direction}Alternatives` as keyof Boundary;

const object: Boundary = { } as Boundary;
const element = object[accessorString]; // number[] | number
```

Or you can filter the `number[]` properties and cast to that:

```
type KeysOfType<T, TValue> = {
  [P in keyof T]-?: T[P] extends TValue ? P : never
}[keyof T]

const direction: Direction = 'top';
const accessorString = `${direction}Alternatives` as KeysOfType<Boundary, number[]>;

const object: Boundary = { } as Boundary;
const element = object[accessorString]; // number[]
```

Comment: This is a super handy utility type, thank you! May I ask, what `[keyof T]` does at the end of the `KeysOfType` definition? Does it give back the index signature of the mapped type before it?

Comment: @cymin The mapped type will filter properties so we get { "propThatMatches": "propThatMatches", "propNotMatched": never}. doing `[keyof T']` will get us all the value types in the mapped type, so `"propThatMatches" | never` which is  `"propThatMatches" ` which is what we want to get, the properties that match the condition

Answer (score 0):

const object: {[K in keyof Boundary]: K extends Direction ? number : number[]} = {...};

and then object[accessorString] would return a type accordingly